# Parsing HHMMSS come from NMEA

Tags: c++, parsing, nmea

I have a trouble with NMEA data(gpzda). The problem is explained below.

NMEA Data : $GPZDA,011856.00,17,03,2018,,*61

My Parsing Code.

```
char hour[2] = { 0 };
for (int i=0; i < 2; i++) hour[i] = utctime[i];
info.tm_hour = atoi(hour);

char min[2] = { 0 };
for (int i=0; i < 2; i++) min[i] = utctime[i + 2];
info.tm_min = atoi(min);

char sec[2] = { 0 };
for (int i=0; i < 2; i++) sec[i] = utctime[i + 4];
info.tm_sec = atoi(sec);

cout << info.tm_year << " | " << info.tm_mon << " | " << info.tm_mday << " | " << info.tm_hour << " | " << info.tm_min << " | " << info.tm_sec << endl;
```

The code is well working, but some time the hour value is strange like a "126". I thought that "6" is add from another memory. How to parse this data to well work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should zero terminate your strings, so declare each one to be of size 3.

`char hour[3] = { 0 };`

and so on

Comment: Why..? hour[0], hour[1] is used. so hour[2] = {0} is right?

Comment: Wrong.

Accessing`hour[2]` yields undefined behavior when you declare the string to have size 2.